# Mac: Virtual Shell Bash Version does not Match Installed Version

Tags: bash, shell, bash4

I am trying to create shell scripts that make use of Bash 4.0's features. I am on a Mac using zshell as my main shell, and I have bash 4.0 installed via Homebrew.

When I run `bash --version` from iTerm, I get:

```
GNU bash, version 4.4.23(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin17.5.0)
Copyright (C) 2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>

This is free software; you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
```

But if I try to execute `echo "Using $BASH_VERSION"` from within my script, I get: `Using version 3.2.57(1)-release`

How do I get my virtual shell for my scripts to point to Bash 4.0?

Comment: `#!/usr/bin/env bash` is a shebang that will use the first shell in the PATH -- the same one `bash --version` checks.

Comment: Closely related: [Why is it better to use `#!/usr/bin/env NAME` instead of `#!/path/to/NAME` as my shebang?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/29608/why-is-it-better-to-use-usr-bin-env-name-instead-of-path-to-name-as-my) on [unix.se]

Answer (score 4):

**homebrew** makes symbolic links in `/usr/local/bin` for everything it installs, so if you want to use **homebrew**-provided `bash`, use:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/bash
...
...
```

---

If you want to see the symbolic link and where it is pointing:

```
ls -l /usr/local/bin/bash

lrwxr-xr-x  1 mark  admin  30 Mar 20 17:16 /usr/local/bin/bash -> ../Cellar/bash/4.4.19/bin/bash
```

---

If you want information about **homebrew** `bash`, use:

```
brew info bash
```

---

If you want to use it as your login shell (I don't like the idea personally), you need to add it to `/etc/shells` and use `chsh` command.

```
$ echo /usr/local/bin/bash | sudo tee -a /etc/shells
$ chsh -s /usr/local/bin/bash
```

then open a new terminal window and verify that it works by executing

```
$ echo $BASH_VERSION
```

Answer (score 1):

Your shell script should start with the line:

```
#!/<path>/bash
```

Which should point to the installed bash you want. Since you seem to be contend with the bash that was found by executing `bash --version`, you can execute `which bash` to tell you where that one is.

Alternately, you can start your script with:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
```

Which will use the bash that is found on your PATH.

Comment: That should be `/usr/bin/env`

Comment: (and `type bash` is more accurate than `which bash`; `which` doesn't know about aliases, shell functions, hashed PATH lookups, or other internal shell state).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Hmmm. I though in this case `which` would have been preferred over `type`, specifically for the reasons you mentioned.

Comment: `which bash` will tell you which one `env bash` will use, not which one `bash --version` used.